# .htaccess only works on some webhosts

Tags: .htaccess

There is something wrong with my .htaccess since it only works on certain hosts.

I try to use the rewrite rule.

`http://example.com/p/page_name` works on all hosts but when I try to add something after `page_name` it doesn't.

### .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule p/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule p/portfolio/([0-9]+)$ p/portfolio&id=$1
```

The last line doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-arrange the 2 rules. Right now the first rule with the regex `p/(.*)$` is gobbling up all requests, including ones that look like `/p/portfolio/1234567`. Also, you can add the `^` character to match the beginning of the URI to make it more accurate and use the `L` and `QSA` flags:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^p/portfolio/([0-9]+)$ /p/portfolio?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or, you can generalize both rules into a single one:

```
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)(/([0-9]+))?$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for. But there is a problem with this: RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)(/([0-9]+))?$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA] it makes $_GET['id'] /id instead of just id

Comment: @NicholasWalker Sorry, it's supposed to be `$3` instead of `$2`

Answer (score 0):

`p/portfolio&id=$1` shouldn't the ampersand be a question mark?